# What is the best practice to fix bad data in one of the table in the database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, database-migration

## Problem

I have a **bad data** in one of my table in my database, and it requires me to **truncate** a table.
I can do it with no problem, **but** what about my team, QAs, and other developers - that already have the code, and bad data. Do they need to truncate their table manually too ? How do people usually deal with something like this ?

---

## Solution

If I truncate that table via **migration script**, is it a **good** idea ?
Is there anything **bad** about it ?
Then, my whole team will just need to run : `php artisan migrate`.

---

I'm open to any suggestions on this.

Comment: What do you mean by bad data? How was it generated?

Comment: **bad data like** : Ex. wrong image path will be one of them. Now, that I found a better way to store my image, and I need to adjust something to those path. With that being said, those old image paths are **deprecated**. Now, here is the problem, when my coworkers load the page, they won't see correct icons. Unless they **truncate** the table, and start upload a new one, then they will continue to have a good image path.

Comment: What's the reason you can't just use `UPDATE` on the bad data to set the bad image paths (for example) to newer fixed image paths, and then inform your team to copy your master tables to their sub tables?

Comment: I think that seeders are literally here for that if you don't like the idea of migration. Though migrations have that "plus" that you can rollback it if that applies to you. It's really up to you using migrations or seeders.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql, you can use mysqldump to dump a copy of correct data and let your team members use it to overwrite their database.

If it's a sqlite, just let them copy over the db file.

Of cause you can use laravel's db seeder to do the work, if you don't mind writing some code.

laravel's migration files are used to define and change schema, not data.

I personally use mysqldump method, because it's easy and lazy, and admin staff can easily learn it.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Your first point, you mentioned `let your team member use it to overwrite their database`. See I tried to avoid to let them do that. I want my site to take care of that, and I don't mind write and extra migration script to achieve that, but since you also mentioned, `laravel migration` is not mean to use for data. Any further hints ?

Comment: laravel's seeder is for data changes, please refer to [laravel.com/docs/seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/seeding). Migration and seeder tools must be handled with care. For example, if you run same seeder twice, you end up with duplicate data. If you roll back migration on production server, you lose all data. If you use mysqldump from time to time, you have extra backup automatically besides your routine backups :)